# selecting, changing css of multiple table cells

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

writing things out helps me to understand better.  I’m trying to figure out how (or the best way) to do this.  I need to write a script that connects the language of a country to the particular country within a table.

- User clicks on a country name (td)
- Language list appears (in a td in a separate table)
- Language of that particular country and the country name is blue and bolded (active state) in both tables
- Current TD “active” state is returned to normal when user clicks on a different TD in the country table.

Manually creating the table in HTML and using individual classes of each TD pair to associate the country to the language.  Thing is, I’d have to write a code for each TD because of the classes.  This works, but I only want the selected TDs to be "active" and the others to return to normal.

CSS

```
td {cursor:pointer;}
td.active {color:blue;font-weight:bold;}
```

HTML

```
<table id=tbl-country>
<tr><td class=”esp”>Espana</td></tr>
<tr><td class=”france”>France</td>  </tr>
<tr><td class=”italia”>Italy</td></tr>
</table>
<table id=tbl-language>
                     <tr>< td class=”espanol">Espanol</td></tr>
     <tr> <td class=”francais”>Francais</td> </tr>
     <tr> <td class=”italiano”>Italiano</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tbl-language").hide();      
    $("#tbl-country td").click(function(){
        $(".tbl-language").show();
        });
    $("td.espana").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $("td.espanol").toggleClass("active");

    $("td.france").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $("td.francais").toggleClass("active");
        });

    $("td.italia").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $("td.italiano").toggleClass("active");
        });
});
```

Comment: How you create the tables does not affect the highlight function. There is no real "best option". Everything depends on your requirements.

Comment: That wasn't my question - how creatng tables effects highlight function.  The examples I gave showed my options of how to tie/bind the table cells of two different tables.  I have included my requirements.  There is always a better/best option.  Nothing is exempt from improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I correctly understood your requirements, this is what I would do:

- If the  data is provided as a tuple list in an external file (json/ js array), I would loop through the data to render it on the HTML
- If the data is to be hardcoded in HTML, I'd follow the way you've done :)

However, my HTML would look something like this:

```
<table id="tbl-country">
<tr><td class="country" id="country-1" data-id="1">Espana</td></tr>
<tr><td class="country" id="country-2" data-id="2">France</td>  </tr>
<tr><td class="country" id="country-3" data-id="3">Italy</td></tr>
</table>
<table id="tbl-language">
     <tr><td class="lang" id="lang-1" data-id="1">Espanol</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="lang" id="lang-2" data-id="2">Francais</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="lang" id="lang-3" data-id="3">Italiano</td></tr>
</table>
```

And my JS would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tbl-language").hide();
    $("#tbl-country .country").click(function(){
        $("#tbl-language").show();
        var cId = $(this).data("id"); //jQuery >= 1.4.3 otherwise $(this).attr("data-id");
        //Remove active state from all
        $('#tbl-country .country').removeClass('active');
        $('#tbl-language .lang').removeClass('active');
        //Add active state only to the matching Country and Language
        $('#country-' + cId).addClass('active');
        $('#lang-' + cId).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Sample Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2xDyS/

Comment: +1 Thanks, TJ-  This is exactly what I wanted to do -- you made it very easy to follow as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flexible jQuery script to use any markup, as long as and data-* attributes are set:

```
<ul id="list1" class="linked-list" data-related-to="#list2">
    <li data-key="en">sdfhgfghgh</li>
    <li data-key="ru">e5ge45</li>
    <li data-key="de">rtzhezhu</li>
    <li data-key="fr">rtgz4t6</li>
</ul>

<table id="list2" class="linked-list" data-related-to="#list1">
    <tr data-key="en"><td>sdfgdfghgfhj</td><td>3456345635</td></tr>
    <tr data-key="ru"><td>qwesqwes</td><td>567867897890</td></tr>
    <tr data-key="fr"><td>ijkzuikujui</td><td>123123123</td></tr>
</table>
```

Link two HTML tables or lists with each other and highlight related rows in both tables on a mouse event using jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    /* select cross-linked lists/tables via some class or a comma-separated list of id's */
    $( '.linked-list' ).each( function() {

        var $this = $( this );

        if( $this.attr( 'data-related-to' ) ) {

            var rows = $this.find( '[data-key]' );

            var relatedTo = $( $this.attr( 'data-related-to' ) );
            var foreignRows = relatedTo.find( '[data-key]' );

            rows.each( function() {

                var currentRow = $( this );

                currentRow.on( 'click', function() {

                    rows.removeClass( 'active' );
                    currentRow.addClass( 'active' );

                    foreignRows.removeClass( 'active' );
                    if( currentRow.attr( 'data-key' ) ) {
                        var foreignRow = foreignRows.filter( '[data-key="' + currentRow.attr( 'data-key' ) + '"]' );
                        foreignRow.addClass( 'active' );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }

    } );

} );
```